# How do i fix security application not responding?

Tags: performance

I can't even play online games due to the security application not responding all the time and it reduces my performance

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming question. What security application? You're probably better off finding a community forum for the application you're referring to (whatever it may be)

Comment: Angelo, I'm wondering what sent you here to ask this question. Did someone tell you that StackOverflow answers questions like this? Did you read it somewhere?